# How to solve a linear system with more variables than equations with constraints

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear system with 6 equations and M>6 unknowns, and no independent terms:

$a_{1}x_{1}+...+a_{M}x_{M}=0$
$b_{1}x_{1}+...+b_{M}x_{M}=0$
$c_{1}x_{1}+...+c_{M}x_{M}=0$
$d_{1}x_{1}+...+d_{M}x_{M}=0$
$e_{1}x_{1}+...+e_{M}x_{M}=0$
$f_{1}x_{1}+...+f_{M}x_{M}=0$

where $a_{1} ... f_{M}$ are known parameters.

I want to find a solution to this system in which all the variables are as close as possible to 1 (not $\pm 1$). All I can tell (guess) so far is that I want $\sum_{j=0}^{M}x_{j}$ to be as close as possible to M, but not sure how to go about it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the system

$ A x = 0 $

where $ A $ is $6 \times M$ with $M \gt 6 $.  The solution is the

$ x = B u $

where $B $ is $ M \times p $ , with $  M - 6 \le p \le M $.  The columns of $B$ form a basis for $\operatorname{ker}(A)$ (The kernel or null space of $A$).

Now define $v = [1, 1, \dots , 1]^T $

You want to minimize

$ f = (x - v)^T (x - v)  = ( B u - v)^T (B u - v) = u^T B^T B u - 2 u^T B^T v + v^T v$

The dimension of $B^T B$ is $p \times p$ and it is invertible, and positive definite.  Hence $f$ is convex and its minimum is at

$ u^* =  (B^T B)^{-1} B^T v $

And the corresponding solution $x^*$ is

$ x^* =  B (B^T B)^{-1} B^T v $

Comment: Thanks a lot @Faaz, this is working wonders! I just wanted to ask, is there any way to ensure that all solutions of x are positive? Thanks again!

Comment: I have no idea how to ensure that the solution has all its components positive.